# When should you use the use keyword vs the loader keyword in Webpack 2?

Tags: webpack

I am trying to migrate to Webpack 2 an I am a bit confused. On this link it says that we should replace module.loaders with module.rules and it looks like loaders syntax is replaced with use that can have objects within an array that has loader as property:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/

But further down it says: `// Do not use "use" here` When it is not an array, but a single loader.

This is a bit confusing and I don't understand it. When should I use "use" and when should I use "loader" / "loaders" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, when you have one file type that uses multiple loaders, use "use". e.g.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                ...cssLoaders,
                lessLoader
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                ...cssLoaders,
            ],
        },
        {
            enforce: 'pre',
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            include: assetsDir,
        },
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            include: assetsDir,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)($|\?)/i,
            loader: 'url-loader',  // Inline images if they're less than 2 KiB
            options: {
                limit: 2048,
                name: '[name]-[sha1:hash:hex:10].[ext]',
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff2?|htc)($|\?)/i,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[name]-[sha1:hash:hex:10].[ext]',
            },
        },
    ],
},
```

Comment: When I use options like that I get a deprecated warning.

Comment: @Alex Be more specific. What's the warning? I suspect you're referring to this one: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/422

Comment: (node:5408) DeprecationWarning: loaderUtils.parseQuery() received a non-string value which can be problematic, see https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56
parseQuery() will be replaced with getOptions() in the next major version of loader-utils.

Comment: Also the rules use syntax throws error with ExtractTextPlugin. Even if it is the newest version.

Comment: @Alex Yeah, that deprecation warning is because not all the loaders have been updated for webpack 2. It's most likely coming from the babel-loader if you have that. Did you read [this section about ExtractText](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#extracttextwebpackplugin-breaking-change)? If you did, and still can't figure it out, create a new SO question. Also, post your webpack config there.